# Doesn't enter admin panel

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I can’t enter the admin panel

Going to Authorization - 
I enter the data, everything is correct, and loading is in progress, nothing else happens, if you enter the wrong data, then everything correctly knocks the error

[image]

Debt long loading, nothing happens, I try to create a user through CLI, change the settings in the database

I checked everything as they write everywhere, it did not help me

Maybe someone had the same problem and who can help me

Thanks

Comment: have you checked that htaccess file is in root?

Comment: Yes, everything is right there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is also an known error in Magento 1 sometimes.
Try some stuff to find your problem:

1. Enable PHP errors and check them
2. Add error reporting in index.php

   `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Set this to true

```
`$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true;`
```

3. check /var/report
4. check system.log and make sure logging is activated in cms

You should also clear your sessions, cache, cookies.
Enough memory on your Webserver?